# Waiting for Async calls to finish

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, win-universal-app

I'm working with the Philips Hue, and I need to get some information from the hue bridge before I can populate my application. The requests are made via HTTP/JSON. I have no issue when I run all my code `async`, but when I try to break out my code so that I have a separate method to update the UI upon loading I'm getting a `System.NullReferenceException` on myLights. I'm assuming that's because my `startUpProcedure()` isn't finished yet, hence myLights has not been set. I can't seem to figure out how to wait for the `startUpProcedure()` to finish before I run `setupUI()`.

To further back that up, if I just run `startUpProcedure()` without `setupUI()` I get no issues. And then if I run `setupUI()` from say a button click it runs just fine.

Clearly I'm missing something here. I just can't seem to find the answer.

So to succinctly put the question: How do I wait for these Async calls to finish so that I can use variables that are depended on their return values?

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {

    public string appKey;
    public string myIP;
    public IEnumerable<Light> myLights;
    public ILocalHueClient myClient;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        startUpPocedure();


        setupUI();

    }

    public async Task startUpPocedure()
    {
        await startUp();

        await getLights();
    }

    public async Task startUp()
    {
        if (await findBridgeIP())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Bridge Found...");
            //Do Actions
        }
        else
        {
            //Error!!
            Debug.WriteLine("No hue found");
        }

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        try {
            appKey = localSettings.Values["appKey"].ToString();

            Debug.WriteLine("appKey loaded: " + appKey);

            //Load up 
            myClient = new LocalHueClient(myIP);

            myClient.Initialize(appKey);

        }
        catch {
            Debug.WriteLine("Need to register app");
        }

    }

    async Task getLights()
    {

        myLights = await myClient.GetLightsAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine("Light Count " + myLights.Count());

        IEnumerable<string> myLightNames;

        List<string> myTempList = new List<string>();

        foreach (Light l in myLights)
        {
            myTempList.Add(l.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(l.Name);
        }

        myLightNames = myTempList;

        comboBox_LightSelect.ItemsSource = myLightNames;

    }

    private void setupUI()
    {
        //Populate the Combo Box
        IEnumerable<string> myLightNames;

        List<string> myTempList = new List<string>();

        foreach (Light l in myLights)
        {
            myTempList.Add(l.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(l.Name);
        }

        myLightNames = myTempList;

        comboBox_LightSelect.ItemsSource = myLightNames;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startUpPocedure` method in MainPage constructor returns Task almost immediately, and because you're not awaiting it, code execution goes to the next line right after that and `setupUI` gets called. So when your code starts to enumerate `myLights` collection, it's still null because `startUpPocedure` and therefore `getLights` are still running.

Problem is, you can't await asynchronous methods in a constructor, so in your case solution will be to move both `startUpPocedure` and `setupUI` to single async method, await them inside this method and call it from constructor similar to this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();    
    Startup();        
}

private async void Startup()
{
    await startUpPocedure();   
    setupUI();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should leave only `InitializeComponent` in the constructor, and move all other logic to `Loaded` event handler,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded

Then you can mark that handler as `async`, and use `await` in it to await on async methods.